# Plotting values over time in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of values: `b=read.csv('https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/b.csv')`

I would like to plot them with having values 1:2000 on the x-axis representing time and the values of the vector on the y axis.

When I plot them using `hist(b)` I get the opposite thing with values from 1:2000 on the y axis and the actual values on the x.

How can I reverse this?

Comment: Are you wanting a `histogram` or a `scatter plot`? If it's the latter, try `?plot`

Comment: can you please fix the link - it is easier to come up with an example then ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `barplot(b)` or `plot(b,type="b")` instead.

(Your link doesn't work for me.)

Comment: I would like the values to represent a quantity so going from 1 to 2000 I would like to have for 1: 47; 2:72, 3:88 etc. So showing the number for each timepoint. ideally with bars

Comment: so the dataset goes from 1 to 2000 and each point has a value. I would like to display each value with bars over time. not just a point but a whole bar starting from 0 and reaching until the value at the given timepoint